# Connecting Ubuntu with Olympus VN-960PC

Tags: 10.04, hardware, camera

I have followed the steps here:
http://www.piotrkrzyzek.com/olympus-vn-480pc-working-in-linux-odvr/

and here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=207104&page=2

I have download the i386 version.

If I do:
`$ sudo odvr`

I get the device listed:
`Model: VN-960PC`

Great.

If I try to run a command however,  I get:

```
Failed to open Olympus device:
couldn't claim interface
```

Wondering if someone else have had this issue or similar, and if not, what would you do to try to solve it?

Comment: I'm so lamm ahahaha I was doing $sudo odvr instead of sudo odvr, hence, not working. ehehe sorry. :D

Comment: So... is your issue solved, or do you still need help?

Comment: @All Sorry. Indeed. It's solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any answers are unnecessary - the question writer said he has solved his problem, typing the `$` by accident.

Comment: I would say by lameness.(if such word exits) :D